# Can't get this JQuery animate to work

Tags: jquery

On my site there are two bags with div ids "cloud" and "cloud2", and they are inside a div "sky"

The JQuery script below is supposed to move the bags/clouds to the right, but I can`t get it to work.

Can you please tell me what I`m doing wrong?

I`m a bit of a newbie, so please keep that in mind when answering. Thanks for your help

```
<script>
    var cloudMoved = false;
    var cloud2Moved = false;

    $(init);

    function init()
    {
        cloudMove();
        cloud2Move();
        }

    function cloudMove()
    {
        if (!cloudMoved)
        {
            $("#cloud")
                .css("left", $("#cloud").offset().left)
        }

        $("#cloud")
            .animate(
                {
                    left: $("#sky").width()
                },
                cloudMoved ? 180000 : 150000,
                "linear",
                function()
                {
                    $(this)
                        .css("left", -parseInt($(this).css("width")))
                    cloudMoved = true;
                    cloudMove();
                }
            )
    }

    function cloud2Move()
    {
        if (!cloud2Moved)
        {
            $("#cloud2")
                .css("left", $("#cloud2").offset().left)
        }
        $("#cloud2")
            .animate(
                {
                    left: $("#sky").width()
                },
                cloud2Moved ? 120000 : 60000,
                "linear",
                function()
                {
                    $(this)
                        .css("left", -parseInt($(this).css("width")))
                    cloud2Moved = true;
                    cloud2Move();
                }
            )
    }



    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
.custom #sky
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 131px;
    overflow: hidden;
}  


.custom #cloud
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    top: 15px;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 120px;
    height: 91px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.custom #cloud2
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
        z-index: 3;
        top: 65px;
    width: 101px;
    height: 66px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe if you add semicolons to a few of your statements, the code should work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cloudMoved = false;
    var cloud2Moved = false;

    function init() {
        cloudMove();
        cloud2Move();
    }

    function cloudMove() {
        if (!cloudMoved) {
            $("#cloud").css("left", $("#cloud").offset().left);
        }
        $("#cloud").animate({left: $("#sky").width()},
                cloudMoved ? 180000 : 150000,
                "linear",
                function() {
                    $(this).css("left", -parseInt($(this).css("width")));
                    cloudMoved = true;
                    cloudMove();
                });
    }

    function cloud2Move()
    {
        if (!cloud2Moved) {
            $("#cloud2").css("left", $("#cloud2").offset().left);
        }
        $("#cloud2").animate({left: $("#sky").width()},
                cloud2Moved ? 120000 : 60000,
                "linear",
                function() {
                    $(this).css("left", -parseInt($(this).css("width")));
                    cloud2Moved = true;
                    cloud2Move();
                });
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(init);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Michael - gotta agree with D Franks regarding the code. Run your js through http://www.jslint.com/. It may help solve some problems before they happen.

Comment: you added a document ready function at the bottom. do i need that?

Comment: I have not tested it differently, but you may not. My goal was to first make sure that init() exists before it is called.

Comment: @D Franks: `init` will exist even if it's declared after it's called as long as it's in the same script tag (and scope) due to function hoisting.

Comment: I`ve changed a few things according to people`s suggestions, but right now my browswer`s saying there`s a parse error on Line 154, but I can`t figure it out.  Can you see it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: $("#cloud").animate({left: $("#sky").width();}, shouldn't have that ; after the width()

Comment: Something I didn't notice until just now: remove the semicolon from both lines that use `left: $("#sky").width();` @Steerpike: Beat me to my error!

Comment: I removed it, but it`s still not working :((((  Note, I reduced it down to one cloud/bag to make it simpler but alas...

Comment: Are you sure? In my browser, I see your one cloud slowly moving to the right.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked to doesn't include any extra javascript code aside from including the jquery library and google analytics. This makes it pretty hard to figure out what might be going wrong :)

Here's a few potential issues:

- You have malformed HTML

  <\div id="sky><\div id="cloud">

(No closing " after sky)

- You don't have a document.ready() holding your jquery calls so it's likely trying to run the code before the page has completed rendering.
- You don't have any javascript doing any work loading in the page (this one is a bit of a biggy)
- $(init); is a reference not a call. To call the init function you need to do init();

Comment: I`ve changed a few things according to people`s suggestions, but right now my browswer`s saying there`s a parse error on Line 154, but I can`t figure it out.  Can you see it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: left: $("#sky").width(); should not have a ; at the end

Comment: o.k, it`s working now that I got a document ready in. Thank you.

Comment: someone else also helped me with the semi-colons (and the code for the document ready) so I gave them the "accepted answer" but I really appreciate your help. wish I could split it somehow...I owe you

Answer (score 0):

not tested, but it seams the following should rather be in the jquery.css() style;

```
.animate(
    {
        left: $("#sky").width()
    },
```

rewrite to

```
....
.animate(
    {
        left: $("#sky").width() + "px"
    },....
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the attribute of your `cloud` div is malformed:

```
<div id=" cloud"="">
```

Should be

```
<div id="cloud">
```